# Posting multiple modals on the same page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have multiple modal windows to edit the user profile in my Laravel app. A modal to edit the description, one to edit Hobbies and so on. 
Using one modal works fine because I can post it to the profile page but the thing is, I want to post all modals to the same page and that's why is not working, I'm aware of this.

Here's what I mean:

```
  Route::put('/user/profile/edit','UserController@putDesc');
  Route::put('/user/profile/edit','UserController@putRate');
```

The modals are pretty basic forms where I set up the action to point to UserController method. 
How should I make the routing in this case? I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::put('somelink', ['uses' => 'SomeController@someFunction', 'as' => 'one-route');
Route::put('someolink', ['uses' => 'SomeController@someOtherFunction', 'as' => 'two-route');
```

etc.

And into your view if you are using LaravelCollective you can do this like that:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'one-route']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'two-route']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If you are not using LaravelCollective put into action attribute

`{{route('one-route')}} or {{route('two-route')}}`

Answer (score 0):

If all modals are part of profile and you want to save data to DB every time user edits something in modal, you should put all modals inside the form and use single route to update whole form:

```
Route::put('/user/profile/update/{id}','UserController@update');
```

Another approach is to use AJAX query for update data from every modal. If data is similar in all modals (like simple text inputs) you can use one route to handle AJAX requests. If data is different, use multiple routes:

```
Route::post('/user/profile/updateDesc','UserController@updateDesc');
Route::post('/user/profile/updateRate','UserController@updateRate');
```